# Process() : - How to identify The PID of process when has been open from Process()?

Tags: macos, cocoa, process, foundation, nstask

I am developing osX app,
I need to open another App from MyApp

```
func openAnotherProcess(command:[String])
    {

        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = /PATH FOR WHICH WANT TO OPEN/
        task.arguments = command

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.launch()
}
```

The above line successful open Application and window. this application has many window. But I want windowId of that window which has been open from MyApp.

I am able to get all running window but not able to distinguish the pericular WindowId

Comment: The *title* of your question isn't the same as the question you go on to ask: the title refers to process IDs, but the question is ultimately about getting the window ID of a specific window from another app. Can you clarify? Also, is there a reason you aren't using `NSWorkspace` to launch the process?

Comment: true @PaulPatterson